# Is there anyway to write data to multiple tables of redshift using a single firehose delivery stream

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am passing some json data to firehose delivery stream which in the end is getting saved into Redshift table. For my use case, I want the data to be stored in different tables.

Do I create different delivery stream for different tables?
If I create it that way, there will be data duplication in S3 as the data must go through S3 in order to push data to Redshift using Firehose delivery stream.

Answer (score 12):

From the Kinesis Firehose [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/faqs/):

> Q: Can a single delivery stream deliver data to multiple Amazon Redshift clusters or tables?
>
> A single delivery stream can only deliver data to one Amazon Redshift cluster and one table currently. If you want to have data delivered to multiple Redshift clusters or tables, you can create multiple delivery streams.

You will need multiple streams.